# convert between FILE type and filedescriptor in C

Tags: c, file, fseek

LANG: C  \  OS: Linux

I am writing a streaming program, I already implemented Play, stop and pause functionlities, when I came to implement seek, I got into the following problem and I got stuck.

For opening the file before streaming I am using the following method:

```
int transport_fd = open(tsfile, O_RDONLY);
if(transport_fd < 0) 
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "can't open file %s\n", tsfile);
                    close(sockfdstr); // using this to stream 
                }
// .....
//.....
len = read(transport_fd, send_buf, packet_size); // here, the read function takes fd as a first argument.
```

To use **fseek()** function, I should pass a *pointer* of type *FILE* as an opened file to seek into, i.e pass a file pointer to the already **opened** stream, so how should I handle this?

Sample dummy code:

```
FILE *fp;
{CODE TO CONVERT BETWEEN *fp AND tsfd - OR ANY OTHER FIX TO THIS SITUATION}
tsfd = fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_CUR);
len = read(tsfd, send_buf, packet_size);
```

Comment: Perhaps `fileno` could do what you want (assuming Linux)?

Comment: Richard; yes I'm using linux as mentioned first line, but **fileno** is a bad idea to think about it as a fix, and everybody say stay aeay from it when you can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the lseek function for your purpose.
You already used open and read instead of fopen and fread, just use lseek instead of fseek.

Comment: Thanks guys, didn't try that one, didn't hear lf it also :/ .. will try it and rank the answer :)

Comment: Until now, the code isn't giving any errors while compiling after using lseek() but I think I'm handling signals in a wrong way (code is getting messy) so I am not able to tell if it's actually seeking into the file (which should be the case logically), thanks for the answer @Skunkz